# Count the rows for a pagination, but doesn't return any value

Tags: mysql

Im using this big query to retrieve data from table `posts` if the user is following that other user (hope it make sens =)), and that will be found in `users_followers`.

```
SELECT
    users_followers.user_id, 
    users_followers.follower_since_timestamp,
    p.user_id,
    p.post_id,
    p.post_has_image,
    p.post_image_name,
    p.post_topic, 
    p.post_text,
    p.post_hashtag,
    p.post_timestamp,
    p.post_edit_timestamp
FROM 
    users_followers
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT user_id, post_id, post_has_image, post_image_name, post_topic, post_text,post_timestamp,post_edit_timestamp, post_hashtag FROM posts) p
ON p.user_id = users_followers.user_id
where 
    users_followers.follower_id = :user_id AND post_text IS NOT NULL ORDER by post_timestamp DESC LIMIT :page_size OFFSET :page
```

But now, I'm trying to do a pagination function. And i cannot figure out how to count the rows from the above query.

I have tried adding `COUNT(users_followers.user_id) AS total`.

But strangely it just returns a random row, not even the `total` column.

Answer (score 0):

The `OFFSET` is supposed be number of records/rows you want to offset not the pages. You'll have to calculate the rows to offset and use that, here's one way to do it

```
LIMIT :page_size OFFSET ((:page - 1) * :page_size)
```

As far as returning a random row is concerned, it should not be doing that as long as your page_size is not one. Would be lot easier to check if you can share some sample data and the result you are getting